# How to set a column as numeric when the numbers have 2 or more points in the value?

Tags: r

I have one large data frame in R in which some columns have numbers with 2 or more points.
For example, 100.200.220 and NAs.
When I try to convert this column that is set as character to numeric using as.numeric(), I got the warning "nas introduced by coercion"
I tried to change the points to nothing gsub(".", "", column_of_interest), or to commas using gsub(), but this eliminate the values.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Dot is special and matches any character.  Use fixed=TRUE to turn that off.  `gsub(".", "", column, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck